# MERN: how to do the feature: each admin can see only product they added in the admin panel?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wanna make the feature: each admin can see only product they added in the admin panel. I tried to add 'userId' field to create product controller and then fetch only that users products by adding this code line `const products = await Product.find({ user: req.user._id, ...keyword })` But I ran into an issue with Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. A bit of my code snippets

Create product controller

```
const createProductSeller = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const product = new Product({
    name: 'Sample name',
    price: 0,
    user: req.user._id, //added this line to recognize the user added a product
    image: '/images/sample.jpg',
    gender: 'Sample gender',
    category: 'Sample category',
    countInStock: 0,
    numReviews: 0,
    description: 'Sample descripton',
  })

  const createProduct = await product.save()
  res.status(201).json(createProduct)
})
```

Fetch product controller

```
const getSellersProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
 
  const products = await Product.find({ user: req.user._id, })
  res.json({ products })
})
```

My repo with [code](https://github.com/Governnment/react-ecommerce)

Hope that's gonna help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a if statement to check if the user_id matches the authenticated user, and if that is true, the button/link to edit should show, other wise, show something else. Like having a table of all products available, which has been populated with title, user_id, price etc, then at last column, you write something like:

```
if(product.userId === user.id) { show buttons } else { do nothing /show more information }
```